# How can I delete 'new chat members' messages in telegram group with pytelegrambotapi?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

My code sample (currently not working):

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members', 'left_chat_member'])
def bot_func(message):
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: Could you please specify what "it doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 1):

consider the bot permissions added to the group, this code is sufficient

```
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members', 'left_chat_member'])
async def on_user_joined(message: types.Message):
    print("JOIN message removed")
    await message.delete()
```

Comment: what library is used here?

Comment: I used aiogram.